# Use first result in an asynchronous race/Winner takes all race

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, race-condition

Basically, I want to pit two asynchronous calls against each other, and only use the winner.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this, only how to prevent it.  Is it remotely possible?

Lame pseudo-code:

```
//rigging a race
function MysqlUser()
{
        setTimeout(function(){
                return "mysqluser";
        }, 500);
}

function ADUser()
{
        setTimeout(function(){
                return "aduser";
        }, 1000);
}

function getUser()
{
        var user = null;
        user = ADBind();
        user = MysqlBind();
        //if user != null
        return user;
        //else?
}
```

I'd like (in this instance) for MysqlUser to win out over ADUser.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple `first` function that takes a list of task and calls back with the result of only the first to complete:

```
function first(tasks, cb) {
    var done = false;
    tasks.forEach(function(task) {
        task(function(result) {
            if(done) return;
            done = true;
            cb(result);
        });                   
    });
}
```

Then:

```
function mysqlUser(cb) {
        setTimeout(function() {
                cb("mysqluser");
        }, 500);
}

function adUser(cb) {
        setTimeout(function() {
                cb("aduser");
        }, 1000);
}


first([mysqlUser, adUser], function(user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

This might need some more thought if you want to cope with both  operations failing.